# how can I delete every second element from std::list in cpp?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to delete every second element from std::list but I'm getting segment error (core dump) when I run erase().

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list <int> num_list;
    list <int> :: iterator it;
    num_list.push_back(1);
    num_list.push_back(2);
    num_list.push_back(3);
    num_list.push_back(4);
    num_list.push_back(5);
    cout << num_list.size() << endl;
    it = num_list.begin();
    advance(it, 1);
    for(it; it != num_list.end(); advance(it, 2)) {
        num_list.erase(it);
    }
    for(it = num_list.begin(); it != num_list.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    } 
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where do you initialize `it`?

Comment: @Rup "_What's `advance`_?" [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks, didn't know about that.

Comment: Your `advance(it, 2)` call will run past the end of the list if it has an even number of elements.  Your erase call also invalidates `it`, so advancing it afterwards is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Unrelated: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` should not be used ([Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)). `using namespace std;` should be avoided ([Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Together they amplify some of the other's worst effects and can result in some very odd errors.

Comment: @Rup " it = num_list.erase(it) " do the job. but the for loop doesn't stop because it goes back to 1, how can i make it stop ??

Comment: @PeterRuderman: That looks like an answer - please post it as such. Comments are to help improve the question.

Comment: @MSalters, I think this question should be closed.  The OP's problems relate to fundamental misunderstandings of basic C++.  The question has nothing to do with how to delete every second element from a list (which the OP has already figured out).

Comment: Why should this be closed? Deleting alternating elements is a non-trivial task (due to iterator invalidation). Somewhat surprisingly, it does not appear to be asked before. The code (now fixed) is pretty minimal and causes the error claimed, while the intent is also clear.

Comment: Because the question should really be something along the lines of "how do I erase from a list while traversing it?" (along with a minimal example)

Comment: @PeterRuderman: usually you'd do that with `std::remove_if`. That won't work here, though. So another reason why this isn't such a bad question.

Comment: @MSalters see my answer for `std::remove_if` solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start from the second item: `next(num_list.begin(), 1)`. The `erase` method returns an iterator to the next item of the removed item. So you can use just `++` operator to step 2.

```
int main()
{
    list<int> num_list;
    num_list.push_back(1);
    num_list.push_back(2);
    num_list.push_back(3);
    num_list.push_back(4);
    num_list.push_back(5);
    cout << num_list.size() << endl;

    for (auto it = next(num_list.begin(), 1); it != num_list.end();) {
        it = num_list.erase(it);
        if (it != num_list.end())
            ++it;
    }
    for (auto it = num_list.begin(); it != num_list.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For a good explanation on why your approach does not work, see **Stepan Lechner**'s answer.

A completely different approach using `std::remove_if` and lambda expressions:

```
int main() {
    std::list<int> ints{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    auto position = std::remove_if(ints.begin(), ints.end(),
            [counter = 0](const auto x) mutable {
        return ++counter % 2 == 0;
    });

    ints.erase(position, ints.end());

    for(const auto x : ints) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
```

`std::remove_if`, paired with `erase` methods calls, is **the** algorithm for removing particular elements from a range. Here, it gets a little tricky - we want to remove every *second* element, so we need a predicate, which will return `true` only for the even positions in the list. We achieve it using a member counter initialized with lambda init capture.

EDIT: As correctly stated by **MSalters** in the comments, using `std::list::remove_if` is a superior solution to `erase-remove` idiom from `<algorithm>`. It takes advantage of internal `std::list` implementation, plus it's simply *less awkward to type*:

```
// *ints* being the list itself
ints.remove_if([counter = 0](const auto x) mutable {
    return ++counter % 2 == 0;
});
```

as opposed to the original:

```
auto position = std::remove_if(ints.begin(), ints.end(),
        [counter = 0](const auto x) mutable {
    return ++counter % 2 == 0;
});

ints.erase(position, ints.end());
```

Comment: There's a `std::list::remove_if` which does not require the `.erase`.

Comment: @MSalters that is indeed the superior solution. I have added that to my answer

Answer (score 4):

Erasing an element of a list invalidates the respective iterator, such that it must not be used for dereferencing or `advancing` any more. Iterators pointing to other elements than the erased one, however, are not affected.

So you just need to remember an iterator position to be deleted and advance the original iterator before erasing the "toDelete"-position:

```
int main()
{
    list <int> num_list;
    num_list.push_back(1);
    num_list.push_back(2);
    num_list.push_back(3);
    num_list.push_back(4);
    num_list.push_back(5);

    size_t size = num_list.size();
    cout << size << endl;

    list <int> :: iterator it = num_list.begin();
    while(size--) {
        auto toDelete = it;
        it++;

        if (size%2==1)
            num_list.erase(toDelete);
    }

    for(it = num_list.begin(); it != num_list.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A bit overkill to keep two state variables (`size` and `it`) but it works.